# How to Customize Bootstrap carousel, button and dropdown js in latest version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, customization

Since, version 3.4.1 bootstrap allow customize js and css files(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/).

In latest version, how can i customize  carousel, button and dropdown js and css.